# Background images moving at different speeds despite being set to the same speed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-animation

Below is the GameView Class, where the background is drawn and moved around, and below that is the background class.

Here is a link to a video visually showcasing the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpSa3.jpg

Here is the tutorial video that I referenced to make the background move:
https://youtu.be/RQoT9BUsl1Q

GameView Class:

```
package com.example.warren;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean isPlaying;
    private int screenX, screenY;
    public static float screenRatioX, screenRatioY;
    private Paint paint;
    private Background background1, background2;
    private int Δx = 0, Δy = 0, x = 0, y = 0, pressed = 0;
    int backgroundSpeed;
    private boolean backgroundOneMove = true, backgroundTwoMove = false;


    public GameView(Context context, int screenX, int screenY) {
        super(context);
        this.screenX = screenX;
        this.screenY = screenY;
        screenRatioX = 1080f / screenX;
        screenRatioY = 1920f / screenY;
        backgroundSpeed = 10; //This is the variable which both the background speeds are set too

        background1 = new Background(screenX, screenY, getResources());
        background2 = new Background(screenX, screenY, getResources());

        background2.x = screenX; 

        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isPlaying) {
            update();
            draw();
            sleep();
        }
    }

    private void update() {
//Moves the background(s) 10 pixels towards the left
        background1.x -= backgroundSpeed * screenRatioY; 
        background2.x -= backgroundSpeed * screenRatioY;

       //If the background has moved off of the screen then this executes. This statement works, and background1 is being reset at the proper time.
        if (background1.x + background1.background.getWidth() < 0 && backgroundOneMove){
            background1.x = screenX;
            //background2 was constantly executing the if statement below, so I decided to link it to background1's timing to ensure it works properly.
            backgroundOneMove = false;
            backgroundTwoMove = true;
        }

        if (background2.x + background2.background.getWidth() < 0 && backgroundTwoMove) {
            background2.y = screenX;
            backgroundOneMove = true;
            backgroundTwoMove = false;
        }

               
            }

            

    }


    private void draw() {
        //Surface view object has been properly activated
        if (getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) {
            Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas(); //Returns the current Canvas that is being displayed on screen.
            canvas.drawBitmap(background1.background, background1.x, background1.y, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(background2.background, background2.x, background2.y, paint);

            //Draws the bitmap that we want to draw on the screen
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void resume() {
        isPlaying = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }

    public void pause() {
        try {
            thread.join(); // Terminates the thread;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Background Class:

```
package com.example.warren;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class Background {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    Bitmap background;

    Background(int screenX, int screenY, Resources res){
        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.oolala); //Set to background image
        background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, screenX, screenY, false);

    }
}
```

Help is much appreciated!! Between me and my teammate, we've spent about 8 hrs trying to fix this.

Comment: Is this line `background2.y = screenX;` meant to set the `y` value?

Comment: First off, thanks so much for looking through my code! Secondly, I can't believe I missed that error. It definitely lessens the effect, but for some reason the screens are still going at different speeds. Perhaps my computer is sentient cause I swear it's not doing what it's told.

Comment: It may help to change the second `if` statement inside the update method to be `else if`, that way it will prevent background 2 from updating more often than it should because of the result of the first `if` statement updating the `backgroundTwoMove` variable